# android rest client giving error of internal server error 500 (using retrofit okhttp and gson)

Tags: android, rest, azure, retrofit, okhttp

I am creating a android rest client for a .net web api (MS azure). I am using jars:

retrofit 1.7.1 
okhttp 2.0.0 
okhttp-url-connection 2.0.0 
okio 1.2.0 
gson 2.3

But getting an error 500 Internal server error for POST data on server. :(
My Code is:

**RestApi.java :**

public interface RestApi {

```
@Headers({
    "Accept: text/xml",
    "User-Agent: REST-Client",
    })
@POST("/api/Account/Register")
void sendPerson(@Body Person body, Callback<StatusData> callBack);
```

}

**MainActivity.java**

```
   RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
    .setEndpoint(API_URL)
    .setLogLevel(LogLevel.FULL).setLog(new AndroidLog("xx--LOG--xx"))

    .build();

    RestApi post = restAdapter.create(RestApi.class);


    post.sendPerson(new Person(), new Callback<StatusData>() {


        public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
                System.out.println(retrofitError.getMessage());
        }

            public void success(StatusData arg0, Response arg1) {
                System.out.println("barcode: " + arg0.created_at);

        }
    });
```

**StatusData.java**

public class StatusData {

```
final String status;
final String created_at;

public StatusData() {
       this.status = "";
       this.created_at = "";
   }
```

}

**Person.java :** is just a POJO class for
name
username
password
city
address
phone
pincode

please help me???????

Comment: I hope the problem is with your .Net code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your .Net server would accept only xml you should setConverter (XML Converter) on your RestAdapter. Refer http://square.github.io/retrofit/

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
.setEndpoint("https://api.soundcloud.com")
.setConverter(new SimpleXMLConverter())
.build();
```

Comment: "SimpleXMLCoverter() cannot resolve error. Is that part of Retrofit??

Comment: It works with Simple (http://simple.sourceforge.net/). Refer https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-converters/simplexml I think you need add dependency to download Simple Xml Serializer